# HDD being detected but not able to read anything from it

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb

I got here from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/137393/old-hdd-is-not-getting-detected-when-connected-through-usb) but it's not my case so I wanted to make sure I am doing everything in my hand to help my family with an oldish HDD.[an oldish HDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005MQO300)

Initially I recommended them buying something [like this](https://www.amazon.es/SATA-Cable-Adaptador-para-Drives/dp/B073QG493V/), which when connected to their laptop or my PC shows this

[image: D Unit USB, translated]

And when I try to open or read it shows [image: which translates to "Inswert Disk in UNIT USB D]

At this point I get lost. I've been trying options from posts like this [posts like this](https://es.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/fix-please-insert-a-disk-into-removable-disk.html), which again, cheaply translated is a Spanish post with 6 possible solutions, but I tried a couple to no avail. I also tried following an English post that I can't find right now, with no success.

Is there anything that can be done? When connecting the disk to the PC, both lights of the adapter light up, but it does not seem to do anything. In my PC I have an SSD so I dont think I have the wires required to connect it as an internal disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the cable supply 12 VDC at 0.55 A from a USB 3.0 or 3.1 port? That's 6.6 W, or, with an 85% efficient power supply in the cable, it would draw 1.6 A from the 5 VDC USB 3.0 port alone, with another 0.7 A needed for the 5 VDC HDD supply. [USB 3.0 power specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Power_and_charging) were originally **far** less, 0.15 to 0.5 A at 5 VDC, not 2.3 A minimum that would be needed by the HDD shown.

Perhaps that cable could power something with much lower requirements, but **your HDD needs a *powered*** SATA drive adapter enclosure, [similar to this.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JGT17B8)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I am trying to look for an equivalent in my local amazon, would this work? https://www.amazon.es/AKDSteel-Electronics-Conversion-Accessories-regulations/dp/B08MQ19DL9/ Either that or a bit more expensive https://www.amazon.es/BianchiPatricia-Converter-External-Drive-Adapter/dp/B07XLK4W64/

Comment: Since I haven't used such an adapter, I can't give you valid advice, but ask at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , Hardware Recommendations.